# Issue with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, cacheable

I had an apex method with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) and a wire method in LWC, all was working fine.

Then to meet the new requirement I was experimenting with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false). With this config the LWC refused to run the apex method with this error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "body": {
        "message": "Apex methods that are to be cached must be marked as @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)"
    },
    "headers": {}
}
```

I set it back to (cacheable=true) but the 500 error is still appearing, I tried hard refresh, closing the browser but it doesn't not help.

What can I do to get the original behaviour back?

Comment: go to setup -> session settings and remove persistence caching

Comment: Double check that you really did manage to reset the cacheable directive in your apex and either logout from the org entirely then sign in again (may reset the cache) or use session settings as @ytiq said, to turn off caching.

Comment: BTW, wires require cacheable methods. You would have to switch to imperative invocation to use a non-cacheable method. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and had everything correct but was still getting the same error.

I had to change the Apex method name and use the new Apex method's name in the .js file. Salesforce is weird sometimes... -_-

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this issue by simply redeploying the lwc component that calls the Apex method

Answer (score 1):

Apex method with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` and a wire method in LWC is actually fine.

Because wire adaptor use browser cache to store the record data coming from `@wire`. By default `@AuraEnabled` is `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)` which means the **server side method (apex method) can't be called by wire adaptor**, therefore LWC refused to run the apex method with this error.

**But imperative call to the apex method is possible without `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`**.

Imperative call doesn't use browser cache to store received data.

Answer (score 1):

`@wire` cannot call `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)`.

You might need to modify your LWC component using imperative call.

From Salesforce Documentation
[Wire Apex Method to Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-wire-method.html)

> Remember that the method must be `static`, and `global` or `public`. The method must be decorated with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`